# the "look to Verb" pattern's meaning and usage

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, verb-pattern

I, once by a teacher, was taught that *look to verb* can only be used in the meaning where you're seeking or finding something, e.g. *I am looking to get a decent place to stay for a night.*

But, recently I've heard *The attorney doesn't look to be hurt* from a YouTube video featuring a court scene in the US. The defendant in the trial suddenly attacked his attorney. The narrator of the video said that expression stating the state of the attorney after the attack. In this case, *look to be hurt* doesn't seem to mean seeking to be hurt, but rather *seem to be hurt*.

So, can the *look to verb* pattern be used in either way?

Each and every response and answer will be appreciated.

Comment: As a British English speaker I would use _seem to be_ - but you would have to search Google Ngrams to find out how common the expression is.

Comment: I'd say *[to be] **looking to** [do something]* (*Intending* to do it) is primarily an ***informal British English*** usage (an *idiomatic* usage, not immediately comprehensible if you don't already know the expression). Completely different to the cited usage here, where ***look*** is simply an alternative to ***appear***, with both terms having the same standard *literal* meaning.

Comment: *The attorney doesn't look to be hurt* is fairly literal phrasing, meaning *It doesn't look as though the attorney is hurt*. But *The attorney **isn't looking to be** hurt* is an unlikely example of that completely different informal BrE usage, which would mean *The attorney **isn't deliberately trying to be** hurt*. Or more sensibly, *The attorney **is trying to avoid** being hurt*, as exemplified by ***I'm not looking for trouble*** in a pub argument (= *Let's not fight!*).

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for sharing the knowledge from the British English perspective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your detailed answers which help a lot. :)
But then, can I conclude that *The attorney doesn't look to be hurt* is equivalent to *The attorney doesn't seem to be hurt*? And such usage is of ***look to be hurt*** fairly acceptable and natural?

Comment: Yes, it's correct that *The attorney doesn't look to be hurt* is equivalent to *The attorney doesn't **seem** to be hurt* (or ***appear, give the impression of being,...***). Personally I think this exact usage is informal, and primarily BrE - but I could be wrong on either or both of those points. You can reasonably "accept" @JavaLatte's answer, I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I (BrE) feel that "looking to [verb]" is more an American turn of phrase. This NGram graph seem to support that opinion: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looking+to+get%3Aeng_us_2019%2Clooking+to+get%3A+eng_gb_2019&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clooking%20to%20get%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooking%20to%20get%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers "looks to be" seems to be as common in US English as UK English. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looks+to+be%3Aeng_us_2019%2Clooks+to+be%3A+eng_gb_2019&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clooks%20to%20be%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooks%20to%20be%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for providing kind, detailed knowledge of yours. Now I think I can conclude, even after taking the account of JavaLatte's comments, that it is at least regarded as informal in BrE.

Comment: @JavaLatte: I suspect the higher prevalence for ***looking to get*** is mostly just down to the fact that ***get*** is used more generically in AmE. I see no significant difference if I chart [*looking to **buy***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looking+to+buy%3Aeng_us_2019%2Clooking+to+buy%3A+eng_gb_2019&year_start=1969&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) over the past half-century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look?q=look%20), "look to *verb*" actually means that you are hoping or planning for something, so the example you provided means

> I am [hoping/planning] to get a decent place to stay for a night.

If you are seeking something, you say **look for**.

The usage in the paragraph that you quoted is one of the normal meanings - **seem**:

> The attorney doesn't seem to be hurt

The reason that me meaning isn't what you expected is the **be** word.

> The attorney doesn't look to ...

This means that the attorney is hoping or planning to hurt somebody.

Comment: I made a mistake in wording it and you're right it's planning rather than seeking.

To check if I understood you correctly about the original point asked about, do you mean the quoted sentence is correct and equivalent to *The attorney doesn't seem to be hurt*? If so, is this a normal way of saying this? I've never heard the ***look to be*** used in the same way ***seem to be*** is used before.

Comment: @SmartHumanism: yes, that's right- it means the same. **looks to be** is uncommon- roughly one occurrence for every 60(AmE)/70(BrE) **seems to be**- but it is used and understood.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I appreciate it. Would you regard such a use of *looks to be * to be a legit expression that can be used in formal speeches or essays?

Comment: @SmartHumanism I would stick to **seems to be** for formal contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help. Make it a great day and night.